# Pass a controller to $ionicModal

Tags: ionic-framework

I am wondering if you can pass a controller to the $ionicModal service. Something like.

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
  scope: $scope,
  controller: 'MyModalCotroller'
})
```

A little context: I would like to have a modal that is distributed across the app and I dont want to repeat all the methods (hide, show, buttons inside the modal) in every controller and I would like to remove the methods from the 'Main Controller' to keep things clean. This would encapsulate the functionality of the modal.

Is there a way to do this.?
Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just add the controller you want to use in the body of the html of the modal. I created a fiddle to show you an example based off the one provided in the ionic docs: http://jsfiddle.net/g6pdkfL8/

But basically:

```
<-- template for the modal window -->
<ion-modal-view>
<ion-content ng-controller="ModalController">
 ...
</ion-content>
<ion-modal-view>
```

Comment: Thanks this is a very simple and effective approach. Wonder why didn't I think of that.

Comment: But, It seems that this way the modal object is not available in the controller.

Comment: A simple solution for that would be to open your modal and set `$rootScope.modal = modal` in the promise. Then just inject $rootScope into the modal controller.

Comment: Or, I just thought of this, you can pass the $scope to the modal normally and use $scope.$parent.modal. (I just updated the fiddle to show this)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMO. Short, simple, sweet. Thanks @RipTheJacker

Comment: What's strange is that while `$scope.$parent` allows me to call functions on the parent scope, it doesn't allow me to change values in it. Any idea why not? For example, see my fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g1xpb7d6/

Comment: Figured it out! For one, ur pen has the first controller scoped to only a button. But more importantly, that context is nested fairly deeply under the original controller. Use `$scope.$parent.$parent.$parent` to actually change the intended scope. Or on the parent scope I added `$scope.topScope = $scope` which let me bypass the chained `$parent`s. See updated pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwpaxJ

Answer (score 25):

There's no direct way of doing so in ionic. However, if you really want to have some common code being segregated at one place,
You can use services to do so. Here' how.

> 1. In your modal declaration, pass scope as null, also the modal declaration should move in a service.

```
app.service('utilsService', function($ionicModal) {

    this.showModal = function() {

        var service = this;

        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
          scope: null,
          controller: 'MyModalCotroller'
        }).then(function(modal) {
            service.modal = modal;
            service.modal.show();
        });
    };

    this.hideModal = function() {
        this.modal.hide();
    };

});
```

---

> 2. All your common methods will also move down into the same service.

---

> 3. Add the reference to this service into your controller's scope.

```
    app.controller('indexController', function($scope, utilsService) {
        $scope.utilsService = utilsService;
    });
```

---

> 4. Now, you can call all the common methods from the view directly using this service.

```
e.g. <button ng-click="utilsService.hideModal()">Hide modal</button>
```

Comment: Seems legit. I will deff try this one. Thnks. I'll wait a little bit for more answers and if none come by i'll check the "accept answer" since apparently, and as you said, "There's no direct way of doing so in ionic".

Comment: @JuanSolano, this approach is flexible and at the very same time, prevents any pollution to the rootscope.

Comment: This part is obviously not needed and copied from the original question `controller: 'MyModalCotroller`, right?

Answer (score 21):

Based on this question and other needs I create a service that can be useful.

Anyway use the CodePen code, this updated, improved and it makes available the parameter 'options' of $ionicModal.

See this post: [Ionic modal service](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-modal-service-like-angular-ui-bootstrap-modal-review/15357) or see in operation: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/julianpaulozzi/pen/wBgpjM)

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var serviceId = 'appModalService';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, [
    '$ionicModal', '$rootScope', '$q', '$injector', '$controller', appModalService
]);

function appModalService($ionicModal, $rootScope, $q, $injector, $controller) {

    return {
        show: show
    }

    function show(templateUrl, controller, parameters) {
        // Grab the injector and create a new scope
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
            ctrlInstance,
            modalScope = $rootScope.$new(),
            thisScopeId = modalScope.$id;

        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(templateUrl, {
            scope: modalScope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function (modal) {
            modalScope.modal = modal;

            modalScope.openModal = function () {
                modalScope.modal.show();
            };
            modalScope.closeModal = function (result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
                modalScope.modal.hide();
        };
        modalScope.$on('modal.hidden', function (thisModal) {
            if (thisModal.currentScope) {
                var modalScopeId = thisModal.currentScope.$id;
                if (thisScopeId === modalScopeId) {
                    deferred.resolve(null);
                    _cleanup(thisModal.currentScope);
                }
            }
        });

        // Invoke the controller
        var locals = { '$scope': modalScope, 'parameters': parameters };
        var ctrlEval = _evalController(controller);
        ctrlInstance = $controller(controller, locals);
        if (ctrlEval.isControllerAs) {
            ctrlInstance.openModal = modalScope.openModal;
            ctrlInstance.closeModal = modalScope.closeModal;
        }

        modalScope.modal.show();

        }, function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function _cleanup(scope) {
        scope.$destroy();
        if (scope.modal) {
            scope.modal.remove();
        }
    }

    function _evalController(ctrlName) {
        var result = {
            isControllerAs: false,
            controllerName: '',
            propName: ''
        };
        var fragments = (ctrlName || '').trim().split(/\s+/);
        result.isControllerAs = fragments.length === 3 && (fragments[1] || '').toLowerCase() === 'as';
        if (result.isControllerAs) {
            result.controllerName = fragments[0];
            result.propName = fragments[2];
        } else {
            result.controllerName = ctrlName;
        }

        return result;
    }

  } // end
})();
```

Usage:

```
appModalService
 .show('<templateUrl>', '<controllerName> or <controllerName as ..>', <parameters obj>)
 .then(function(result) {
     // result from modal controller: $scope.closeModal(result) or <as name here>.closeModal(result) [Only on template]
 }, function(err) {
     // error
 });
```

You can use another service to centralize the configuration of all modals:

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('myModals', ['appModalService', function (appModalService){

var service = {
    showLogin: showLogin,
    showEditUser: showEditUser
};

function showLogin(userInfo){
    // return promise resolved by '$scope.closeModal(data)'
    // Use:
    // myModals.showLogin(userParameters) // get this inject 'parameters' on 'loginModalCtrl'
    //  .then(function (result) {
    //      // result from closeModal parameter
    //  });
    return appModalService.show('templates/modals/login.html', 'loginModalCtrl as vm', userInfo)
    // or not 'as controller'
    // return appModalService.show('templates/modals/login.html', 'loginModalCtrl', userInfo)
}

function showEditUser(address){
    // return appModalService....
}

}]);
```

Comment: First of all Julian for your great work!  One question in your codepen example your myModal factory has return service; line. But above it does not -I assume that is typo.

Comment: Yes you are right. I posted this solution in various topics and not updated everyone. Anyway use the CodePen code, this updated, improved and it makes available the parameter 'options' of $ionicModal.

Comment: Hi @julianpaulozzi, this is a great work. I made it to a module for myself. I just want to thank you. https://github.com/wataruoguchi/ionic-ui-modal-service/tree/master

Answer (score 5):

Create a directive to be used inside the modal and inside the directive you can assign the modal it's own controller and scope. If someone wants some example code I can put something up.

Comment: BY far the simplest of all suggested approaches.  SO much that I feel stupid I didn't think of it...  Own controller can be redundantly included anywhere = duh.

Comment: Directives can be a scary thing for many. But that's simply the answer they're looking for :P

Comment: Example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a simple way to attach a controller to a modal instance and manage all modals with a single service. Also, I wanted the modal to have it's own isolated child scope. I wasn't satisfied with using `ng-controller` and I found other answers to be overly complicated to the point where you could easily loose track of scope and end up with circular or unidentifiable dependencies. I created the following service for my purposes.

You can pass an optional `parentScope` parameter to explicitly assign a parent scope to the created modal scope.

You could easily modify the `instantiateModal` method to accept $ionicModal options as an argument - I just didn't have the need for it.

BTW - I'm using the Webpack babel-loader for transpilation and the html-loader to load the templates. But, in it's simplest form, it's just a basic service.

```
/**
 * nvModals
 * @description A modal manager. Attaches a specified controller to an $ionicModal instance.
 */

import myModalTemplate from '../common/modals/my-modal.html';
import otherModalTemplate from '../common/modals/other-modal.html';

let nvModals = function (
    $rootScope,
    $controller,
    $ionicModal
) {

    var _self = this;

    _self.methods = {
        /**
         * Instantiate and show a modal
         */
        showMyModal: (parentScope) => {
            var parentScope = parentScope || null;
            _self.methods.instantiateModal('MyModalController', myModalTemplate, parentScope)
                .show();
        },
        /**
         * Instantiate and show another modal
         */
        showOtherModal: (parentScope) => {
            var parentScope = parentScope || null;
            _self.methods.instantiateModal('OtherModalController', otherModalTemplate, parentScope)
                .show();
        },
        /**
         * Instantiate a new modal instance
         *
         * @param  {object} controller  Controller for your modal
         * @param  {string} template    Template string
         * @param  {object} parentScope Optional parent scope for the modal scope
         * @return {object}             Modal instance
         */
        instantiateModal: (controller, template, parentScope) => {
            var modalScope;

            if(parentScope) {
                modalScope = $rootScope.$new(false, parentScope);
            } else {
                modalScope = $rootScope.$new(false);
            }

            $controller(controller, {
                '$scope': modalScope
            });

            modalScope.modal = $ionicModal.fromTemplate(template, {
                scope: modalScope,
                animation: 'slide-in-up'
            });

            modalScope.$on('modal.hidden', (evt) => {
                evt.targetScope.$destroy();
                if (evt.targetScope.modal) {
                    evt.targetScope.modal.remove();
                }
            });

            modalScope.hideModal = function () {
                modalScope.modal.hide();
            };

            return modalScope.modal;
        }
    };

    return _self.methods;
};

nvModals.$inject = [
    '$rootScope',
    '$controller',
    '$ionicModal'
];

export default nvModals;
```

> In your controller...

```
$scope.modals = nvModals;
```

> In the associated template

```
ng-click="modals.showMyModal()"
```

> In the modal template

```
ng-click="hideModal()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have seen a lot of different solutions to better handling Ionic modals because of the lack of a controller option or something similar.
After playing with React for a while I came up with another option, more declarative in my opinion. Is in ES6 and just a prototype but you can have an idea:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  @Inject('$scope', '$ionicModal', '$transclude', '$rootScope')
  class Modal {
    constructor() {
      let { animation, focusFirstInput, backdropClickToClose, hardwareBackButtonClose } = this;
      $transclude((clone, scope) => {
        let modal = this.createModalAndAppendClone({
          scope,
          animation,
          focusFirstInput,
          backdropClickToClose,
          hardwareBackButtonClose
        }, clone);
        this.setupScopeListeners(modal.scope);
        this.createIsOpenWatcher();
        this.addOnDestroyListener();
        this.emitOnSetupEvent(modal.scope);
      });
    }
    setupScopeListeners(scope) {
      scope.$on('modal.shown', this.onShown);
      scope.$on('modal.hidden', this.onHidden);
      scope.$on('modal.removed', this.onRemoved);
    }
    addOnDestroyListener() {
      this.$scope.$on('$destroy', () => {
        this.removeModal();
      });
    }
    createIsOpenWatcher() {
      this.isOpenWatcher = this.$scope.$watch(() => this.isOpen, () => {
        if (this.isOpen) {
          this.modal.show();
        } else {
          this.modal.hide();
        }
      });
    }
    emitOnSetupEvent(scope) {
      this.onSetup({
        $scope: scope,
        $removeModal: this.removeModal.bind(this)
      });
    }
    createModalAndAppendClone({
      scope = this.$rootScope.$new(true),
      animation = 'slide-in-up',
      focusFirstInput = false,
      backdropClickToClose = true,
      hardwareBackButtonClose = true
    }, clone) {
      let options = {
        scope,
        animation,
        focusFirstInput,
        backdropClickToClose,
        hardwareBackButtonClose
      }
      this.modal = this.$ionicModal.fromTemplate('<ion-modal-view></ion-modal-view>', options);
      let $modalEl = angular.element(this.modal.modalEl);
      $modalEl.append(clone);
      return this.modal;
    }
    removeModal() {
      this.modal.remove();
      this.isOpenWatcher();
    }
  }

  function modal() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope: {
        'onShown': '&',
        'onHidden': '&',
        'onRemoved': '&',
        'onSetup': '&',
        'isOpen': '=',
        'animation': '@',
        'focusFirstInput': '=',
        'backdropClickToClose': '=',
        'hardwareBackButtonClose': '='
      },
      controller: Modal,
      bindToController: true,
      controllerAs: 'vm'
    }
  }

  angular
    .module('flight')
    .directive('modal', modal);

})();
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
<modal is-open="vm.isOpen" on-shown="vm.onShown()" on-hidden="vm.onHidden()" on-removed="vm.onRemoved()" on-setup="vm.onSetup($scope, $removeModal)">
  <div class="bar bar-header bar-clear">
    <div class="button-header">
      <button class="button button-positive button-clear button-icon ion-close-round button-header icon" ng-click="vm.closeModal()"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <create-flight-form on-submit="vm.submit()"></create-flight-form>
  </ion-content>
</modal>
```

You open and close the modal with a boolean value bind to is-open and then register callbacks for the different events.