# Can’t get ng-show/ng-hide to work in ion-header inside ion-modal-view ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ng-show/ng-hide to switch between two different header titles. It works in the browser but does not work in android (4.1) in a cordova app. I also tried using ng-switch and also ng-if, but the same net result.

```
<ion-modal-view>         <<<<< it works OK when not in an $ionicModal
 <ion-header-bar>
  <h1 class="title" >
    <span ng-hide="clipboardMsg">{{title()}}</span>
    <span ng-show="clipboardMsg" class="clipboard-msg">{{clipboardMsg}}</span>
  </h1>
  <button class="button button-clear button-primary" ng-click="close()">Close</button>
 </ion-header-bar>
 ...
```

Apologies for the cross-post but I will really appreciate some help.

Comment: not sure if this is your problem or not, but this answer might help -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434262/pass-a-controller-to-ionicmodal

Comment: @sfletche thanks for the interesting link. It doesn't address my present issue but interestingly enough I have built a similar "service" with mixins so I now have a chance to improvise.