# navigate to another page without reloading the controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I want to navigate to another page without reloading the controller:

```
  .state('app.viewcomments', {
    url: '/viewcomments/?new',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/posts/view-comment.html',
        controller: 'SearchController'
      }
    }
  })
```

What i want is if I navigate to this url from anywhere it should not reload `SearchController` based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974271/can-you-change-a-path-without-reloading-the-controller-in-angularjs)  it tried :

```
  <a href="#/app.viewcomments/?new" class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-round"></a>
  <a href="#app.viewcomments/?new" class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-round"></a>
  <a href="app.viewcomments/?new" class="button button-icon icon ion-plus-round"></a>
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Persisting data is usually a job for factories or services

Comment: actually have form that i need to open frequently so i dont want to reload the controller whenever i came back from that form page

Comment: The question you linked uses a parameter to load different partials into the same view (hence no controller reload). It also uses ng-route instead of ui-route so you can't directly compare your case to his.

Comment: Why you don't want to reload the controller? Is there a notable performance issue? Usually the user is by far the slowest component in the system. If you don't have any issues I'd just create a new instance as it is. KISS - Keep it simple, Stupid{

Comment: i load data when controller is loaded. now let say i open a form and then want to go back then again it will load the same data again inside controller

Comment: i found this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/27453442/1049104